# date.newinstance returns wrong year and month

Tags: apex

```
Date firstDate = Date.newInstance(2021, 10, 1);
```

When i run the above code in anonymous block it works correctly but the year and month mismatches if i run from the class. how to fix this issue?

Output:

[image: returns the following results]

```
   public static wrapRecord getFirstDayAndLastDayofMonth(Integer year, Integer Months, Integer day)
    {
        
        Date firstDate = Date.newInstance(year, Months, day);
        System.debug('Res##:'+firstDate); // returns wrong values
        Date firstDay = firstDate.toStartOfMonth();
        Date lastDay = firstDate.addDays(Date.daysInMonth(firstday.year(), firstday.month()) - 1);
        
        wrapRecord wraps = new wrapRecord();
        wraps.firstDayOfMonth = firstDay;
        wraps.lastDayOfMonth = lastDay;
        return wraps;
    }
```

Comment: I have never seen apex such as what you have shown above produce the "wrong" date. In what way is it wrong? How do you know? Can you please [edit] the question to add more context and perhaps sample output?

Comment: @PhilW it returns wrong month and year not the date u can run the simple example in anonymous window and and implement the same logic in apex class and check.

Comment: What do you mean it "returns wrong month and year"? How? Please [edit] the question to add the detail.

Comment: Please [edit] to show the code that generates this debug.

Comment: @PhilW i have attached the screen shot to the question

Comment: Show how that is generated please.

Comment: Please add the code for the call to this function, and add how the debug output is generated. If you don't we can't help you sort the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be doing something wrong in your Apex.

If I use the following code:

```
@IsTest
private class AATest {
    @IsTest
    static void testBehavior() {
        Date firstDate = Date.newInstance(2021, 10, 1);

        System.debug(firstDate);
        System.debug(firstDate.year());
        System.debug(firstDate.month());
        System.debug(firstDate.day());
    }
}
```

I get the output:

```
22:11:09.5 (6102515)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|2021-10-01 00:00:00
22:11:09.5 (6181197)|USER_DEBUG|[15]|DEBUG|2021
22:11:09.5 (6212306)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|10
22:11:09.5 (6240805)|USER_DEBUG|[17]|DEBUG|1
```

Comment: public static wrapRecord getFirstDayAndLastDayofMonth(Integer year, Integer Months, Integer day)
    {
        
        Date firstDate = Date.newInstance(year, Months, day);
        System.debug('Res##:'+firstDate); // returns wrong values
        Date firstDay = firstDate.toStartOfMonth();
        Date lastDay = firstDate.addDays(Date.daysInMonth(firstday.year(), firstday.month()) - 1);
        
        wrapRecord wraps = new wrapRecord();
        wraps.firstDayOfMonth = firstDay;
        wraps.lastDayOfMonth = lastDay;
        return wraps;
    }

Comment: Please put your code sample in your question and include the debug statements that generate the debug you included.

Comment: BTW, that the firstDate initialization generates the "wrong values" suggests that the parameters to this function are not receiving the values you expect it to receive. Add debug of those parameter's values as well to check.

Comment: i have debugged the parameters its sending correct data.

Comment: You need to show this code too. How can we help if we don't have the full picture?!

Comment: you are right the parameters are receving wrong data i have not observed that.